# Symfony 2 get user locale in form

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle

I use FOSUser bundle and rewrite registration form, and there i use entity type for select country, region, etc. This entities have relation with user locale, and i want write DQL for each locale. 
How I can get user locale in form without rewriting FOSUser:registerAction?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can get user locale like this `$locale = $this->get('session')->getLocale();` from your controller, or you should pass locale or whole session object into form type constructor defined like this.

#### MyFormType.php

```
use FOS\UserBundle\Form\Type\RegistrationFormType as BaseType;
class MyFormType extends BaseType
{
    private $session;
    public function __construct($session, $class)
    {
        $this->session = $session;
        parent::__construct($class);
    }

    public function buildForm(FormBuilder $builder, array $options)
    {
        $locale = $this->session->getLocale();

        // Build your form as you need
        $builder
            ->add('property', 'entity', array(
                'class' => 'MyBundle:Property',
                'query_builder' => function(EntityRepository $er)
                {
                    // use $locale here
                }
            );
    }
}
```

#### config.yml

```
fos_user:
  registration:
    form:
      type: my_user_registration

services:
  my.registration.form.type:
    class: My\UserBundle\Form\Type\MyFormType
    arguments: [@session, %fos_user.model.user.class%]
    tags:
        - { name: form.type, alias: my_user_registration }
```